# Set text for "next" button using text from next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the html of the next buttons to the contents of `<h2>` in the next div?

```
<div id="survey-1" class='content'>
    <h2>Bob</h2>
    <a href="#" class='next button'></a>                      
</div>

<div id="survey-2" class='content'>
    <h2>Fred</h2>
    <a href="#" class='next button'></a>                      
</div>

<div id="survey-3" class='content'>
    <h2>Joey</h2>
    <a href="#" class='next button'></a>                      
</div>
```

So far I've only got,

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        $('.next').html('Next Student '+$("#survey-"+i).children().html());
};
```

But I want them to be all different... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('.next').each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).parent().next().find('h2').text());
});
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EJaJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this <kbd>[**Demo js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6wUk/1/)</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.next').text(function(){
      $(this).text($(this).prev('h2').text());
    });
});
```

jQuery **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** method - text() method combine text contents of each of element in set of matched elements, including their descendants.

---

Check this <kbd>[**Demo js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6wUk/2/)</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.next').each(function(){
       $(this).text($(this).prev('h2').text());
    })
});
```

jQuery **[each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** method - each() method looping for each method element and execute function.

Comment: You're missing the point of passing a function to `.text()`. You should be returning the new value to set it. The way you're doing it, you might as well be using `.each()`.